# Mixing add_logger_name with AsyncBoundLogger raises an error

Tags: logging, python-asyncio, structlog

When using AsyncBoundLogger with add_logger_name, I get: `AttributeError: 'BoundLoggerFilteringAtNotset' object has no attribute 'name'`
My Code:

```
import logging
import structlog
from structlog import get_logger
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def define_structlog(log_level=logging.INFO, pretty: bool = False, set_bugsnag: bool = False) -> None:
    processors = [
         structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
    ]

    structlog.configure(
         processors=processors,
         context_class=dict,
         logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
         cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
    )


def wrap_async(logger) -> structlog.stdlib.AsyncBoundLogger:
     return structlog.wrap_logger(logger, wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.AsyncBoundLogger)

async def main():
    define_structlog()
    logger = wrap_async(get_logger())
    await logger.info("hay")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Is there is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, needed to add wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger in the structlog.configure function